# mySQL interface error only occuring if ran in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, multithreading

I'm running a web crawler that gets called as a separate thread via Django. When it tries to store the scraped information I get this error:

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 147, in execute
    charset = db.character_set_name()
InterfaceError: (0, '')

If I manually run the script from the command line I don't get this error. Any ideas?

My guess is that I do about 4 cursor.execute()s in one iteration of a loop. Could this be throwing something off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it mentions the character set, my gut says you are running a different Django/Python/something from the command line than you are from the webserver. In your settings file, turn on `DEBUG=True`, restart the server, and then run this again. In particular, look at the list of paths shown. If they are not *exactly* what you expect them to be, then this is a Red Flag.

Comment: @markuz: Seriously? 1.5 years later you suddenly think this answer, which the OP decided was the *correct* answer, is somehow wrong? How long have you been working with production Django sites? How many times have you successfully dealt with a "works in one environment but not in another" type of error?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. For me problem was

```
from django.db import connections
cursor=connections["default"].cursor()
```

Was outside in some other script file.

When I move this line inside the method where I was executing query, it solved the issue

```
cursor=connections["default"].cursor()
```

The learning for me was the connections are not maintained with my previous approach.